# Extract indexes of which elements are lower than a threshold in numpy

Tags: python

How to extract indexes of which elements are lower than a threshold in numpy matrix and then set this indexes to values zero in another same size matrix?

for example:

```
input = [2 3 4 1 6 2 1 7 8]
other_same_array = [12 2 -1 4 2 6 9 3 1]

if threshold = 3
output = [0 2 -1 0 2 0 0 3 1]
```

and this is my code:

```
      m =  np.where(input < threshold)
      other_same_array[m] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not even need the indices, you can just use a boolean mask to index your output array:

```
mask = input < 3
output[mask] = 0
```

I hope that helps.

ref:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays